# How to solve $\tanh(x-y)=\frac{y}{2t}?$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, functions

> How to solve the following equation about variable $y$:
> $$\tanh(x-y)=\frac{y}{2t}?$$
> where $x$ is fixed and for small $t>0$ and large $t<\infty$, there would be different cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With suitable change of variables/constants, the equation can be written in the cleaner form

$$\tanh z=mz+p.$$ You have the intersection(s) of a sigmoid with a straight line. The sigmoid can be roughly approximated by the lines $\tan z\approx z$ and $\tanh z=\pm1$.

If $m<0$, you have a single real solution. For large $p$,

$$z\approx\frac{1-p}m.$$ For tiny $p$,

$$z\approx \frac p{1-m}$$ (and similar formulas for negative $p$).

For $m>1$, you have a single solution, similar to the above case. For $0<m<1$, you have from one to three solutions. The limit case (two roots, one of which is double) occurs when the line is tangent, i.e. when simultaneously

$$\frac1{1-z^2}=m,$$

$$z=\pm\sqrt{1-\frac1m}$$ and $$p=\tanh z-mz.$$

So for given $m,p$ you can tell the number of roots and have them isolated in separate intervals.

[image]

This qualitative analysis should be enough to allow you to use a numerical method such as Newton's iterations and find all roots in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @Yves Daoust's answer, consider that you look for the zero of
$$f(z)=\tanh (z)-(mz+p)$$ If $z$ is small, using Taylor series
$$f(z)=-p+(1-m) z-\frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{2 z^5}{15}+O\left(z^7\right)$$ Now, using series reversion, you would get
$$z\sim\frac{p}{1-m}+\frac{p^3}{3 (m-1)^4}-\frac{(2 m+3) p^5}{15
   (m-1)^7}+\cdots$$

If $z$ is large, I think that what @Yves Daoust proposed would me more than sufficient. Otherwise, writing
$$\frac {e^z-e^{-z}}{e^z+e^{-z}}=\frac {e^{2z}-1}{e^{2z}+1}=\frac m2(2z)+p $$ Make $t=2z$ to get
$$e^{-t}=-\frac {t+\frac{2 (p-1)}{m} } {t+\frac{2 (p+1)}{m} }$$ which would have a solution in terms of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$). Nice to know it but not useful at all.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\tanh (x-y) = \frac{y}{2t}$$
$$\Rightarrow \tanh (y-x) = -\frac{y}{2t}$$
$$\Rightarrow \tanh (x-a) = -\frac{x}{2t}$$
Since $x$ is fixed, wecan replace it by some constant $a$. And replace the y-coordinate in this 1D problem by the $x$ coordinate.

Further taking $X=x-a$, we get
$$\Rightarrow \tanh X = -\frac{X}{2t} - \frac{a}{2t}$$

Since this is a transcendental equation, you cannot have a analytical solution in general. So we go for a graphical solution. LHS is a $\tanh$ function which goes to $-1$ as $X<-1$ and $+1$ as $X>+1$, and a smooth crossover in the intermediate region. While RHS is a straight line with slope $-\frac{1}{2t}$ and a negative intercept.

So, for small $t>0$, RHS can only have a solution: $X=-a$ or $x=-2a$ or in terms of original coordinates, $y=-2x$ is the only solution. But LHS does not have a zero at $y=-2x$. So, the given equation has no solution for small $t$.

And as $t$ goes very large, $X=0$ or rather $y=-x$ is the solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the feeling that you have been absent for a while. Welcome back ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yeah, indeed. I was. Thanks :)

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Sorry, why RHS is a straight line with slope −1? Not $-(2t)^{-1}$? Also, how do you obtain for small $t$, $X=-a$ and for large $t$, $X=0$?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat And if $X=-a$, then $x$ is $0$, right? If $X=0$, $x=a$. Typo?

Comment: @BobO. You are right. The slope mentioned was a typo. As a result, I have changed the answer a bit. See if it makes sense now.